# Node.js: Regex to make sure the string is the first in the line

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I make sure that the string "To:" is at the beginning of the line and not at the middle or end?

This is what I have: `result.match(/To\:(.*)/)[1].replace(/^\s+/, '');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the `^` anchor, i.e. `/^.../`

Keep in mind that this matches the *start-of-string*, which is fine if you read line by line. In case you have multiple lines (i.e. newlines) in your string and you want to allow matches on any such line, use the `m` ("multi-line") modifier: `/^.../m`